# Calculating Greatest Prime Factor of Any Number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I needed an efficient way to solve this problem but I wanted a way to calculate the greatest prime factor of any number. Is there a better way? What do you think about it? (I also saw some answers with square roots methods. How does that work?)

I tried recursion and memoization at one point. And I also tried finding all the factors and checking whether they are prime. Eventually, I came up with this.

```
def next_prime(num):
    while True:
        num = num+2
        if is_prime(num):
            return num


def is_prime(num):
    for x in range(2, num//2):
        if num % x == 0:
            return False
    return True


def greatest_prime_factor(number):
    list = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79]
    for y in list:
        print('y = ', y)
        while True:
            print('number = ', number)
            if number == 1:
                return y
            elif number % y == 0:
                number = number//y
                if is_prime(number):
                    return number
            elif y == list[-1]:
                list.append(next_prime(y))
                break
            else:
                break

print('greatest ', greatest_prime_factor(600851475143))
```

Comment: See if you can figure out how to implement it without ever calling `is_prime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math 
  
def greatest_prime_factor(n): 
    # Initialize max prime factor 
    max_prime = -1
    
    # Determine the number of 2s that divide n
    while n % 2 == 0: 
        max_prime = 2
        n /= 2     
          
    # n is now odd, iterate only for odd integers 
    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2): 
        while n % i == 0: 
            max_prime = i 
            n = n / i 
      
    # Handle case where n is a prime number
    # greater than 2
    if n > 2: 
        max_prime = n 
      
    return int(max_prime)
```

```
n = 25
print(greatest_prime_factor(n)) 
  
n = 123123589503
print(greatest_prime_factor(n)) 

n = 600851475143
print(greatest_prime_factor(n))
```

> 5
>
> 572969
>
> 6857

Comment: Could you further improve the performance of this algorithm by recognizing that any prime number greater than 3 must be of the form `6n±1`, so there are some odd numbers you will not have to consider?

Comment: That could be a potential optimization but I think the time complexity would stay the same. To verify, you could obtain a quantitative reading of the algorithm by timing the execution speed before/after the changes

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that would eliminate a third of the numbers you consider when decrementing by twos, since 6n-3 is divisible by 3.  Would that constitute a linear-time speedup (1/3*O(whatever))?

Comment: It would but when the input is say in the millions, the time complexity would stay the same. From my understanding, if something had `O(n)` time complexity, any constant before it, for instance (`25 * O(n)`), would still equal `O(n)`

Comment: Yes, the time complexity would be the same, though you can still speed up the actual execution. I.e. both will trend upwards in complexity at the same rate, but one may become infeasible before the other.

Comment: Yes I think that optimization will definitely give a performance boost. Using `timeit` to measure execution speed should give the quantitative speed increase :)

Answer (score 0):

I used @nathancy's work as a starting point and slightly optimized the routines to squeeze some performance out. I imagine in-lining the generator would help more, but as-is, at `n=123123589503`, this routine runs in:

```
11.6 ms ± 511 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

vs the original

```
19.1 ms ± 941 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```py
def generate_alternating_seq():
    while True:
        yield 2
        yield 4


def greatest_prime_factor_opt(n):
    max_prime = -1

    if n % 2 == 0:
        max_prime = 2 # only perform one assignment
        n /= 2
        while n % 2 == 0:
            n /= 2

    if n % 3 == 0:
        max_prime = 3
        n //= 3
        while n % 3 == 0:
            n //= 3

    g = 5
    seq = generate_alternating_seq()
    sqr = int(math.sqrt(n))
    for k in generate_alternating_seq():
        if n % g == 0:
            max_prime = g
            n //= g
            while n % g == 0:
                n //= g
        g += k
        if g > sqr:
            break

    if n > 2:
        max_prime = n

    return max_prime
```